# get document.styleSheets by name instead of index?

Tags: javascript, css

[document.styleSheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.styleSheets) is used with an index, 
but what If I want to use [stylesheet.insertRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/stylesheet.insertRule) with a specific CSS file ?

I know the file's name, which is injected to a page and at some point via JS.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use this, and keep in mind:

> *For security reasons, Opera and
> Mozilla will not allow you to access
> the cssRules collection of a
> stylesheet from another domain or
> protocol. Attempting to access it will
> throw a security violation error*

```
function setStyleRule (selector, rule, sheetName) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets,
        stylesheet = sheets[(sheets.length - 1)];
    
    for( var i in document.styleSheets ){
        if( sheets[i].href && sheets[i].href.indexOf(sheetName + ".css") > -1 ) {
            stylesheet = sheets[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if( stylesheet.addRule )
        stylesheet.addRule(selector, rule);

    else if( stylesheet.insertRule )
        stylesheet.insertRule(selector + ' { ' + rule + ' }', stylesheet.cssRules.length);
}
```

---

### Update - shorter code:

```js
function getSetStyleRule(sheetName, selector, rule) {
    var stylesheet = document.querySelector('link[href*=' + sheetName + ']')

    if( stylesheet ){
        stylesheet = stylesheet.sheet
        stylesheet.insertRule(selector + '{ ' + rule + '}', stylesheet.cssRules.length)
    }

    return stylesheet
}

// Usage example
getSetStyleRule('main', 'body', 'background:red')
```

Comment: @vsync, You stated that for security reasons it's not allowed. Why is this a security problem? Exactly, how can it be abused?

Comment: @Pacerier - well I may or may not knew it 5 years ago when I wrote this, but I can't remember nor think of a reason why it would be a security thing. it's only css after-all.

Comment: @Pacerier a hacker can do a lot of damage with CSS. They can completely change the way website looks using background images, hide parts that don't serve their purpose, and use `content` to insert text that doesn't belong to the website. With a modified page like that, they can potentially trick the user into performing actions that he wouldn't have performed otherwise.

Answer (score 25):

Why so complicated? You can get a specific document stylesheet by ID or URL without looping through all the stylesheets in the document:

`var mysheet = $('link#id')[0].sheet;`

... or ...

`var mysheet = $('link[href="/css/style.css"]')[0].sheet;`

Comment: Works perfectly! But can you explain, how you knew, that the required property name was "sheet"?

Comment: I can't remember where I first saw it, but `sheet` is basically the property used to access a stylesheet programmatically.

Comment: Indeed, ".sheet" works perfectly! Unfortunately, there are few informations about this great property. Most people loop through "document.styleSheets".

Comment: Stylesheet is from the [CSS StyleSheet API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet)

Comment: This doesn't work and there is no reference to this method on MDN

Comment: It DOES work. There is nothing special about this method except it is selecting the  `sheet` (or `CSSStyleSheet` if you like) by jQuery. I am using it effectively cross-browser. https://d.pr/i/7TXlZG

Answer (score 6):

Here is a minor adjustment to the answer by vsync.

```
function addRule(stylesheetId, selector, rule) {
  var stylesheet = document.getElementById(stylesheetId);

  if (stylesheet) {
    stylesheet = stylesheet.sheet;

    if (stylesheet.addRule) {
      stylesheet.addRule(selector, rule);
    } else if (stylesheet.insertRule) {
      stylesheet.insertRule(selector + ' { ' + rule + ' }', stylesheet.cssRules.length);
    }
  }
}
```

Once you get the DOM object through document.getElementById you can use the 'sheet' property to access the actual styleSheet. So just make sure that you provide an ID for the styleSheet you want to change. Even if it is an external CSS file, just give it an ID.

And here is my test code:

```js
var index = 0;
var items = [
  { selector: "h1", rules: "color:#3333BB;font: bold 18px Tahoma;padding: 12px 0 0 0;" },
  { selector: "p", rules: "padding:0;margin:0;background-color:#123456;color:#ABCDEF;"},
  { selector: "b", rules: "font-weight:normal;"},
  { selector: "i", rules: "color:#66FF66;" }
];

function addRule(stylesheetId, selector, rule) {
  var stylesheet = document.getElementById(stylesheetId);

  if (stylesheet) {
    stylesheet = stylesheet.sheet;

    if (stylesheet.addRule) {
      stylesheet.addRule(selector, rule);
    } else if (stylesheet.insertRule) {
      stylesheet.insertRule(selector + ' { ' + rule + ' }', stylesheet.cssRules.length);
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    addRule("myStyles", items[index].selector, items[index].rules);
    index++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style id="myStyles">
  div
  {
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
</style>
<button>Click Me 4 times slowly</button>
<div>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <p>Paragraph One</p>
  <p>Paragraph with <b>bold</b> and <i>Italics</i></p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened because of the address of CSS is different of the adress of the page.
To fix is just make the both have the some adress.

Answer (score 1):

Without jquery:

```js
function addRule(stylename, selector, rule) {

  var stylesheet = document.querySelector(`link[href$="${stylename}.css"]`)

  if( stylesheet.addRule )
          stylesheet.addRule(selector, rule);

      else if( stylesheet.insertRule )
          stylesheet.insertRule(selector + ' { ' + rule + ' }', stylesheet.cssRules.length);
        
     }
     
// example use

addRule('styles.css', '.color', 'red')
```