# Move href from html to css

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

Good Day

i have this simple html and i want to move href from html to css

```
<body>
<a href="http://www.xxx.com">xxx</a>
</body
```

what i want is to delete href from html and use it instead in css in any way:

```
<body>
<p>xxx</p>
</body>
```

the css will be

```
p {
"http://www.xxx.com"
}
```

what should i use in p{ } (is it url or link or ... )? is it possible ?

Comment: That's not really possible. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i have the same link in different pages, so if i want to change it , i dont want to go in each page , i will change it in css

Comment: Why not use a language such as PHP or ASP to provide that functionality across the pages? CSS is not the way to go about this.

Comment: Oh ok, you'll need to do that either with Javascript client-side or PHP / ASP server-side as @Ryan has said. Think of CSS as only look and feel, and HTML / Javascript etc. as the action part of it.

Comment: Out of interest, it is possible in IE using a [behavior htc in your css](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530723(v=vs.85).aspx), but that would be an unthinkably terrible thing to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that this can be done by static CSS.
Can be done with jQuery, try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        $this=$(this);
        $p = $('<p></p>').insertAfter($this);
        $p.html($this.text());
        $this.remove();
    });
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/Cmxx9/

If you really desperately need to implement this with CSS, you can try to figure out how to make use of CSS `content` property. Read more about this here: http://css-tricks.com/css-content/

Answer (score 2):

Try with jquery

**HTML**

```
<p>Google</p>​
```

**Jquery**

```
$('p').replaceWith('<a href="http://www.google.com">xxx</a>');​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5wpwW/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

your css makes no sense. A URL can only be used for background-images for example:

```
.myClass {background-image: url(http://www.xxx.com/myImage.jpg); }
```

So what you want to do?

If you want to declair dynamic global css rules you need to do this with javascript.

Like this: [get document.styleSheets by name instead of index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679577/get-document-stylesheets-by-name-instead-of-index)

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. CSS is for optional presentational suggestions, not for changing the functionality of a page. Links are functionality.

To get a solution to your real problem, you need to describe the problem itself, not an assumed solution (like using CSS for setting up links) that cannot possibly work.